# Cannot run unit tests in next 13 with supabase due to: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: next.js, jestjs, supabase, next-router

Trying to run this in my test file and I get this error

```
render(
      <RouterContext.Provider value={createMockRouter({}) as NextRouter}>
        <SignUpPage />
      </RouterContext.Provider>
    );
```

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      10 |   const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
      11 |
    > 12 |   const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
         |                            ^
      13 |     const { name, value } = event.target;
      14 |     if (name === "email") {
      15 |       setEmail(value);
```

It seems that this line in my sign-up function causes it:

```
const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    // event.preventDefault();
    **const supabase = createClientComponentClient();**
    // const { error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
    //   email,
    //   password,
    //   options: {
    //     emailRedirectTo: `${location.origin}/api/auth/callback`,
    //   },
    // });
    // if (error) {
    //   setError(error.message);
    // }
    // if (!error) {
    //   router.push("/verify");
    // }
  };
```

I am really struggling to get this to work, cannot find any info in the docs. If anyone has encountered this issue before it would be great if I could get some assistance!

Cheers

I was trying to render my SignUpPage, I expected the page to render with a mocked submit function. Jest cannot parse the code within the function so I cannot even mock it as I get errors.

Comment: Have you tagged your component with `use client`? See the docs here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs#client-side

Comment: I have solved the issue, I think it is to do with incompatibility with jest and createClientComponentClient from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs". I may make a video detailing what to do if anyone else has this issue.

Comment: A quick fix would help a lot. I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up mocking `createClientComponentClient` in my jest test in order to render a component that included the `<Auth />` component. I tried modifying my Jest and Babel configuration in all sorts of ways and everything but it seems the mock is the only way to make the error disappear.

Here is the mock I ended up using. You may end up having to add some additional properties to `auth` in order to make it work (telltale sign is if you get any new `can't read property of undefined` errors).

```js
jest.mock('@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs', () => {
  return {
    createClientComponentClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        auth: {
          signIn: jest.fn(),
          onAuthStateChange: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
              data: {
                subscription: {
                  id: '123',
                  callback: jest.fn(),
                  unsubscribe: jest.fn(),
                },
              },
              error: null,
              fetching: false,
            }
          }),
        },
      }
    }),
  }
})
```